# How can I insert a variable number of records in one go?

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server

I need to run a variable amount of insert statements. Is it best to run through a loop and execute the query one at a time? Or, is there a way to send all the inserts in one go?

Comment: It would help to have an example or two of your individual inserts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a transaction and batch all the inserts. Not sure about the conditions you're trying to do this under, but if it's code executing SQL statements, just open the connection, start a transaction, execute everything, and then commit the transaction or roll it back if there was an exception.

**Edit** Some pseudocode:

```
SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("my connection string");
SqlTransaction txn = cn.BeginTransaction();

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO MyTable (Field1) VALUES (@Value1)");
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Value1", SqlDbType.Whatever);

cmd.Connection = cn;
cmd.Transaction = txn;

foreach (var value1 in ListOfValues) {
  cmd.Parameters["@Value1"].Value = value1;
  int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}

txn.Commit();
cn.Close();
```

Of course you'll need to enclose this in a try/catch block and rollback the transaction if there's an exception. But this is basically it.

Comment: Could you give an example of this using inline sql?

Comment: @chobo Added an example, not sure if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: if there is an error commiting the transaction can it be rolled back? Nvm I see that you can :)

Comment: Nope, this is pretty much the fastest way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

The second, all the inserts in one go:

```
INSERT INTO ...
;
INSERT INTO ...
;
```

Comment: If one of the inserts fails do the previous inserts stay in the database?

Answer (score 2):

Here's an option for use with older versions of SQL Server including 2000/2005:

```
insert into table(col1,col2)
select 'a',1
union all
select 'b',2
union all
select 'c',3;
```

With SQL Server 2008 you also have the ability to use multiple rows in the VALUES clause:

```
insert into #temp (col1, col2)
values  ('a',1), ('b',2), ('c',3);
```

---

You can also use this techique to build a script from one server to run on another...

Consider the following...

```
create table #temp 
(col1 char(1), col2 smallint)

insert into #temp (col1, col2)
values  ('a',1), ('b',2), ('c',3);

select 'insert into #temp (col1, col2)' as [--sqlcmd]
union all
select 'select '+quotename(col1)+' as col1, '
  +cast(col2 as varchar(10))+' as col2 union all '
from #temp
```

If you output to text and replace the last "union all" with ";" you've got your query ready to run on your second server.

Comment: +1 for the SQL-Server 2008 ability. -1/2 for the `union all` for an `insert`

Comment: De nada. It also works in MySQL. Does it not work in earlier versions of SQL-Server (like 2000 and 2005)?

Answer (score 1):

I do it all at one time, if you just need rows:

```
DECLARE @Table table (RowID int identity(1,1), OtherValue int, String varchar(20))

--for a given number range, generate all numbers including and between that range
DECLARE @StartNumber int
       ,@EndNumber   int
SELECT @StartNumber=8
      ,@EndNumber=17

;WITH AllNumbers AS
(
    SELECT @StartNumber AS Number
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Number+1
        FROM AllNumbers
        WHERE Number<@EndNumber
)
INSERT into @Table (OtherValue, String)
SELECT Number,'wow!' FROM AllNumbers
--OPTION (MAXRECURSION 500)

select * from @Table


RowID       OtherValue  String
----------- ----------- --------------------
1           8           wow!
2           9           wow!
3           10          wow!
4           11          wow!
5           12          wow!
6           13          wow!
7           14          wow!
8           15          wow!
9           16          wow!
10          17          wow!

(10 row(s) affected)
```

if you have actual data that differs for each row then a bunch of inserts is the best you can do.

Depending on where your insert data comes from (user input) you many need to parametize your values to protect against injection.  That will make concatenating many INSERTs together in a single string with ":" between them difficult and potentiall insecure.  In that case a loop over you internal array calling a parametized insert query will be the most secure way.  If your data does not come from user input, you can just execute a query from a long string like:

```
'INSERT table (col1, col2) VALUES (1,2);INSERT table (col1, col2) VALUES (3,4);INSERT table (col1, col2) VALUES (5,6);'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could think out of the SQL Server/Stored Proc box and use Entity Framework and have that do all the work for you.  It really cuts down development time.